# In Dart, Angular2 3.x requires AppComponent to have a getter 'toggled'

Tags: angular-dart

I'm programming a client web app in Dart, using Angular2.

Since Version 3.x of the `dart`'s `angular2` package the `AppComponent` (or whatever class is bootstrapped from `main()`) requires a getter `toggled`. If it's missing, the browser (Dartium) reports an error:

```
VM2848:1 EXCEPTION: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'AppComponent' has no instance 
getter 'toggled'.
Receiver: Instance of 'AppComponent'
Tried calling: toggled
STACKTRACE: 
#0      Object._noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:43)
#1      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:47)
#2      ViewAppComponent0.build 
(package:myproject/app_component.template.dart:140:93)
#3      AppView.create 
(package:angular2/src/core/linker/app_view.dart:180:12)
#4      DebugAppView.create 
(package:angular2/src/debug/debug_app_view.dart:73:26)
```

(etc.)

What is this getter good for? I implemented it as

```
get toggled => () => null;
```

and my app seems to work, but I'd like to know what `toggled` is supposed to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular definitely doesn't require this `toggled` property. It is defined inside your `app_component.html`, I would recommend looking at [bindings] and {{string interpolations}}.

Comment: Thank you. I blindly copied an example from http://dart-http://dart-league.github.io/ng_bootstrap/build/web/index.html#dropdown, which worked with Angular 2.2.0, but not 3.0.0 anymore.